# How to store the output of a two variable function as a matrix

Tags: r

I have constructed in R a two variable integer valued function `f(x,y)` which is only well - defined for single entries (not for example `f(1,1:5)`). I am effectively looking for an integer valued function `F(x,y,z,w)` which would give the output:

`f(x,y),f(x,y+1),...,f(x,w),f(x+1,y),f(x+1,y+1),...,f(x+1,w),...,f(z,y),f(z,y+1),...,f(z,w)`

as a `(z-x+1) by (w-y+1)` matrix. Cheers for any help!

Comment: Whoever has marked this down, please state your reason so I can improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: So two people have voted this down now. My previous question still stands: how can I improve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer` seems to be what you're looking for here.

```
# make a simple function
f <- function(x, y){x+y}
x <- 3
z <- 5
y <- 2
w <- 7
outer(x:z, y:w, f)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
#[2,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[3,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

If it's true that your function really only can take scalars as the input then you may need to use `Vectorize` to make this approach work

```
# Function that can only takes scalars...
f <- function(x, y){if(length(x) > 1 | length(y) > 1) stop('blah'); x + y}
outer(x:z, y:w, f)
#Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : blah
myvectorizedfun <- Vectorize(f)
outer(x:z, y:w, myvectorizedfun)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
#[2,]    6    7    8    9   10   11
#[3,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dason. Would it be possible to adapt your solution to a more general version of the problem: say I have a function with three arguments e.g. `f=f(x,y,z){x+y+z}` and the same restrictions as before. How would I create a function `F(x1,x2,y1,y2,z)` which outputs the same matrix as before for a fixed `z`. e.g. the first line of `F(1,2,1,3,6)` would read `8,9,10` and the second line would be `9,10,11`. Thanks for any input you can give.

Comment: @user1873334 `outer` takes a `...` parameter which passes along any additional parameters onto the function of interest.  So in your case if f is defined like your example you could just do `outer(x:z, y:w, f, z = 6)`

Answer (score -1):

I've found `for` loops to be the most straightforward way to handle matrix creation like this. This is the basic outline for what you're trying to do:

```
F <- function(x,y,z,w) {
    Matrix <- matrix(nrow=z-x, ncol=w-y) # Set dimensions of your matrix
    for(i in 1:(z-x)){                       # Summing over all x
        for (j in 1:(w-y)){                  # Summing over all y
            Matrix[i,j] <- f(i+x,j+y)        # Evaluate and store in matrix
            }}
    Matrix <<- Matrix                    # Assign Matrix outside the function F
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do a global assign instead of just returning the matrix? and I don't think your loop indices are actually what you think they are...

Comment: Fixed the indices. As for the assignment, you can do it however you want it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sure it's possible to do it however you want... but it's terrible practice to store to a global variable.  If you return the result instead of storing to a global there is no possibility of overwriting something and you don't get code that looks magic (ie if we used your way then somebody could call this function and then suddenly later in the code the person is referencing Matrix even though they never explicitely created it... that's bad).  Also your indices _still_ aren't right.  Note that 1:5-3 gives c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2).  You probably want 1:(5-3)